# Scroll to a specific item in recyclerview when clicked on another recyclerView item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have two recycler view one horizontal and one vertical
In my horizontal recycler view, there are categories and in vertical, there is items list. So I need to do that when I click on any category my vertical recycler view scroll to that specific item
Attaching the screenshot in the link - https://ibb.co/n67WdRn
https://ibb.co/P5CrjnH

I have tried using intent and it works but it starts a new activity
Please help

Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseReference reference;
    ArrayList<dish> list;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private ArrayList<String> mCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getCategory();
        menu();

    }

    private void getCategory(){
        Log.d(TAG, "Preparing Categories");
        mCategory.add("Vagetables");
        mCategory.add("Indian Bread");
        mCategory.add("Paranthas");
        mCategory.add("Starters");
        mCategory.add("Snacks");
        mCategory.add("Salad");
        mCategory.add("Noodles");
        mCategory.add("Sandwiches");
        mCategory.add("Rice");
        mCategory.add("Soups");
        mCategory.add("Beverages");
        mCategory.add("Yoghurt");
        mCategory.add("Papad");

        initRecyclerView();
    }

    private void initRecyclerView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init RecyclerView");
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, mCategory);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

  private void menu(){
      list = new ArrayList<dish>();
      Log.d(TAG, "recycler MenuView : Firebase Initialized");

      FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
      reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("dishes");
      reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange : called");
              for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
              {
                  Log.d(TAG,"Adding Menu");
                  dish p = dataSnapshot1.getValue(dish.class);
                  Log.d(TAG, "called : " + p);
                  Log.d(TAG, " : " + dataSnapshot + " : " + dataSnapshot1);
                  list.add(p);
              }
              getmenu();

          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Opps....Somethinf Went wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      });
  }
    private void getmenu(){
        Log.d(TAG,"Setting adapter");
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        RecyclerView recyclerMenuView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerMenuView);
        recyclerMenuView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
        recyclerMenuView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java - Category recyclerview (Click on this item)

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    @NonNull

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";
    private ArrayList<String> mCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> category) {
        this.context = context;
        mCategory = category;
    }

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG ,"On Create View Holder: called");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnBindViewHolder: called");
        holder.category.setText(mCategory.get(position));
        holder.category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onClick : Clicked on Text" + mCategory.get(position));
                Toast.makeText(context, mCategory.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCategory.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView category;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
        }
    }
}
```

MenuAdapter.java - Scroll the item rom this recycler view

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.menuViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<dish> dishes;

    public MenuAdapter(Context c , ArrayList<dish> p)
    {
        context = c;
        dishes = p;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public menuViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d(TAG ,"On Create View Holder: called");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview, parent, false);
        return new MenuAdapter.menuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull menuViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.dishname.setText(dishes.get(position).getDishname());
        holder.dishrate.setText(dishes.get(position).getDishrate());

Picasso.get().load(dishes.get(position).getDishImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).into(holder.dishImage);

        boolean flag = dishes.get(position).getPermission();
        if (flag){
            Log.d(TAG," recommended : " + dishes.get(position).getDishname());
            holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            holder.recommended.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dishes.size();
    }

    class menuViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView dishname, dishrate, recommended;
        ImageView dishImage;
           public menuViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
            {
                super(itemView);
                dishname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishname);
                dishrate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishrate);
                dishImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dishImage);
                recommended = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recommended);
           }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using RecyclerView's `scrollTo(position)` or `smoothScrollTo(position)`

Comment: Pass the position of "that specific item"

Comment: Yes but How can I get that position from my recyclerview adapter to main activity?

Comment: I am tried using intent and it works but problem is it starts new activity for that...

Comment: This IMO has to be solved by looking how your data is structured. I think your dishes should be marked which "category" it belongs to. Then you could query `MenuAdapter` to return the position of first item of a category and make the recycler view scroll to that position.